# How to sync SQLite database with firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

My application uses the SQLite database, but I want to offer the user to access their data on different phones if they want. I don't want to drop SQLite and instead start using Firebase because Firebase needs registration and authentication which for some users is not preferable. The users should have an option, whether they want to register and use firebase or stick to the offline SQLite database.
If the user was offline or logged out of Firebase and then made changes in the data like (add, delete), when the user logged in or backed online, I want the changes to reflect on the Firebase too.
What are some steps that need to be done to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to drop SQLite and instead start using firebase because firebase needs registration and authentication which for some users is not preferable.

If an authentication mechanism with one of the [providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start) is not preferable, then you should consider implementing an [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). What it basically means, it allows you to create an anonymous user, without having to ask for any information.

> The users should have an option, whether they want to register and use firebase or stick to the offline SQLite database.

While this mechanism can be implemented, I cannot see any reason why would you do that, since both, the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), have their own offline persistence mechanism. The latter, for Android and Apple platforms, offline persistence is enabled by default.

> If the user was offline or logged out of firebase and then made changes in the data like (add, delete), when the user logged in or backed online, I want the changes to reflect on the firebase too.

That's what the offline persistence mechanism does. While offline, all operations are added to a queue, and once the device regains connectivity, all operations are synchronized with the Firebase servers.

> What are some steps that need to be done to accomplish this?

In the case of Cloud Firestore, none. In the case of the Realtime Database, simply enable it using this line:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I want when the users installed the app, they right away  be able to use it without sign in even if it's anonymous. Later in the app I'll show  them if they like to sign in or stay offline. Can you show me some steps?

Comment: In that case, things are even simpler. Since you don't want to implement an anonymous authentication either, then the only thing that remains to be done is to create the logic in your app. But please note that signing in and being offline are two totally different things. To be able to authenticate, you have to be online, so you can communicate with the Firebase servers, while simply using the app, there is no need for any authentication, nor to be online, in order to use it.

Comment: So the best thing is to create two databases one in SQLite and one in firebase?

Comment: " there is no need for any authentication, nor to be online, in order to use it. " here I am talking about after the user installed the app, but later I'll show them in a Button or TextView like ( Sign in or Register ) after that I want sync the data between SQLite and firebase.

Comment: No, there is no need to create an SQLite database. When I say that "both, the Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore, have their own offline persistence mechanism" it means that both will save the data locally, so it can be accessed while offline. So there is no need to create an additional database.

Comment: If you want later your users to have the option to register, there will be no problem with that. Add that option whenever you need it. If it's mandatory in your project to use SQLite, save the data in that SQLite database until the users create an account. As soon as it becomes a user of your app, then write all the data from the SQLite into Firebase. That's it.